# In What Line of Code this Exception Happened?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm getting the following exception:

```
-[NSView _registerWithBackdropView] should not be called off of the main thread. Invocation was here:
(
0   AppKit                              0x00007fff7377c5ce -[NSView(NSInternal) _unregisterWithBackdropViewIfNeeded] + 404
1   AppKit                              0x00007fff738b421d -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) _drawViewBackingLayer:inContext:drawingHandler:] + 789
2   AppKit                              0x00007fff738b3f02 -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) drawLayer:inContext:] + 80
3   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff7ba93e3d _ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev + 1155
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff738b2d9a _NSBackingLayerDisplay + 577
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff738a6001 -[_NSViewBackingLayer display] + 885
6   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff7ba87f6e _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 572
7   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff7ba88099 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 35
8   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff7ba7d878 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
9   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff7b974631 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff73a201e6 -[NSUIHeartBeat _heartBeatThread:] + 2516
11  Foundation                          0x00007fff77668c6d __NSThread__start__ + 1243
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8b439aab _pthread_body + 180
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8b4399f7 _pthread_body + 0
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8b4391fd thread_start + 13
)
```

***How can I know in which line of my code this happened?***

The app doesn't crash, I just see the error in Xcode's console.

I know the problem is that there is an UI operation that is *not* being executed in the main thread. But I don't even know where in my code this is happening.

Comment: Seems that you use pthreads in which you tried to make some UI calls.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes, but how can I know the line of code that triggered it?

Comment: Instrument the code and/or use a debugger.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès got it. But could you be more detailed? Which instrument tool are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Apple bug.

I contacted them and they said they will fix it.